# Display mic icon in SearchView always

Tags: android, searchview, searchable

In Android Searchable SearchView the clear(X) icon replaces the mic icon on typing. I want to display both clear and mic icons while typing. Is there a way to do that?

Here are my codes:

res/xml/searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:searchMode="queryRewriteFromText"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:voiceLanguageModel="web_search"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

res/layout/menu_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="search here"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo( getComponentName() ));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);

    return true;
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>
```

Thanks in advance.